# How can I add image into Gridview Databound dynamically using ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, gridview, rowdatabound

I need to add an image icon to gridview databound at runtime in a specific cell.

I started code already but i'm not sure how to accomplish it because using this code the image don't showing in gridview...

See below:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    if (e.Row.DataItem != null)
    {                  
            ImageButton image = new ImageButton();
            image.ImageUrl = "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/img/add-page-red.gif";
            e.Row.Cells[2].Controls.Add(image);
    }
}
```

Any help would greatly appreciate... Thank you.

Comment: Why are you referencing drive c? It should look like  image.ImageUrl = "img/add-page-red.gif";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// In .aspx page use below code-
//for imageUrl you have to call the method which is defined in code behind-

 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
  <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# GetImage() %>'/>
  </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>

// In code behind return the image path-

  public static string GetImage()
    {
            return "../Images/Image.jpg";    
     }
```